# Check if S3 bucket name begins with word?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a python Lambda to check for an S3 bucket in an account. The issue is that the naming of this bucket changes from account to account, with the same phrase in the beginning but randomized letters at the ending.

example:

```
bucketname-bucketregion-jdkaieldjadksl
```

with the name of the bucket, which is always the same, the region of the bucket, which may differ, and random letters, which always differ.

I know that you can check to see if a bucket exists using doesBucketExist, but is there an easy way to do this to check if a bucket **begins** with something?

The way I was thinking of doing this was getting all the buckets, then iterating through them to see if any name contained the `bucketname` but I'm worried this isn't a good approach.

Comment: Simplest way is to list all bucket and check names. Another option would be to maintain a list of buckets somewhere, e.g. DynamoDB or even a JSON file in S3 and simply maintain that as buckets are added and deleted. You could do that programmatically by running a script periodically or you could trigger a Lambda function via CloudTrail when buckets are created and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the bucket names and check if the name prefix matches.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
  if bucket.name.startswith('bucketname-bucketregion-'):
      print(bucket.name)
```

Comment: Or better... `if bucket.name.startswith('bucketname-bucketregion-'):`